# Corrupted HTTP headers on Apache/Weblogic 9.2

Tags: apache, spring, caching, http-headers

I have a very strange problem. My application stack is J2EE based and uses Spring 2.5.6 with Spring webflow 2.0.6. The app server is Weblogic 9.2 with an Apache server in front (load balancing). We use SiteMinder Webagent as the authentication layer in apache.

The problem below could be caused by any of the layers above -

Our site performance is very slow and the reason being, certain javascript and css files are not being cached. We know that Siteminder strips away the If-Modified header so we enabled IgnoreExt parameter (in WebAgent)to add .js & .css extension to existing list of unprotected file types (without this NO JS or CSS files were cached). The problem now is that I see only 2 files not being cached (i.e. the server does not return a 304) and the reason being the response headers are corrupted. The server does return a 304 but there ae some junk text in the headers and therefore the client is not able to decide where to get the content from. It looks like this -

[alt text http://img187.imageshack.us/img187/2358/dojo.gif](http://img187.imageshack.us/img187/2358/dojo.gif)

[alt text http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/2087/tundra.gif](http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/2087/tundra.gif)

**Now this could be known problems with the 2 files (part of Spring Webflow) or a configuration in Apache with SiteMinder or something else entirely. Anybody ever come across this? Any idea where to start looking?**

Comment: I'd suggest you start narrowing down the problem by removing some components until you find the offending component (eg: siteminder, apache).

Answer (score 0):

We were having a similar situation running Apache 2.0.59 with WebLogic 10mp2.  Intermittently, we would find data sitting in front of a valid HTTP response.  The data was always a gzipped 0 after a 304 Not-Modified response.  The corrupt header begins with the signature 1F 8B 08...

The issue seemed to stem from the use of mod_deflate with cached resources.  We have been able to eliminate the issue by disabling mod_deflate.  To date, we have disabled mod_deflate wholesale, but are working on narrowing down where we disable mod_deflate.  The Apache WebServer project alludes to a fix in 2.1.1:

*) mod_deflate: Don't deflate responses with zero length 
     e.g. proxied 304's [Allan Edwards]